# Using Report Name as parameter in class

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am new to C# but i am trying to create class to load all reports and pass the report name for it

```
public void ReportQuery(string DTTable,string query, ReportClass RPTT )
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {               
        db.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.Fill(ds, DTTable);

        RPTT rpt= new RPTT();                    
        rpt.Load("~/RPTSales.rpt");
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[DTTable]);
        this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
    }
}
```

I get error on  `RPTT rpt= new RPTT()`;

> 'RPTT' is a variable but is used like a type

How can I pass the report name as parameter ?

Edit :
this is the original code which i am trying to create class for it since i am loading lots of reports using it:

```
 using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            if (ds.Tables["RPTSales"] != null)
            {ds.Tables["RPTSales"].Clear();}                
                db.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from sales", con);
                da.Fill(ds, "RPTSales");
                Reports.RPTSales rpt = new Reports.RPTSales();
                rpt.Load("~/RPTSales.rpt");
                rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["RPTSales"]);
                SetDBLogonForReport(cn, rpt);
                this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;                
        }
```

after edit the class code and once i try to call it :

```
 ReportQuery("RPTSales", "select * from sales",Reports.RPTSales );
```

i get error about     Reports.RPTSales

```
Error   'RPTSales' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

Comment: RPTT is your method's parameter... you can't `new` it.
I think you might direct to use `RPTT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RPTT` is already an instance of the class. You're trying to use an instance of the class as if it were a class itself. Instead of trying to do

```
RPTT rpt= new RPTT();
```

Just use the RPTT parameter.

```
public void ReportQuery(string DTTable,string query, ReportClass RPTT )
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {               
        db.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.Fill(ds, DTTable);

        RPTT.Load("~/RPTSales.rpt");
        RPTT.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[DTTable]);
        this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPTT;
    }
```

Comment: it worked fine but once i try to pass the RPTT as parameter gives Error      'RPTSales' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

RPTSales is the report name

Comment: @Eslam Waheed  Could you put the code about `ReportClass` ?

Comment: @daniel.shih ReportClass is the report name which i want to load original code added

Answer (score 1):

Your original post had little context around its usage, and you said RRPT is report "name", but i assume you mean it is the subclass?

In that case, use templating: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Something like this (untested):

```
public void ReportQuery<T>(string DTTable,string query) where T : ReportClass
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {               
                db.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                da.Fill(ds, DTTable);

                T rpt= new T(); // Or just `T rpt = T()` if error here
                rpt.Load("~/RPTSales.rpt");
                rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[DTTable]);
                this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        }
```

Very little context in orginal post, but does that seem to answer your actual question?

Comment: gives me error      Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint

Comment: @EslamWaheed - then remove the `new` keyword, ```T rpt = T()```

Answer (score 1):

On original code `Reports.RPTSales` is a Type,So you might create a instance be a parameter to method.

```
ReportQuery("RPTSales", "select * from sales",new Reports.RPTSales());
```

In `ReportQuery` method you can use `rpt` object to do data databinding.

```
public void ReportQuery(string DTTable,string query, Reports.RPTSales rpt)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {               
        db.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.Fill(ds, DTTable);                  
        rpt.Load("~/RPTSales.rpt");
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[DTTable]);
        this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
    }
}
```